# Why my image can't be displayed and is undefined?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, axios

I would like to display an image which have a src as result of a node function but I only have :
Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'image_resto'). But if I console.log(RestaurantInformations), I can see that response.data is working correctly.
Any ideas please ?

Here is my component:

```
import React from 'react';
import Axios from 'axios';
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react';

import './gererMonRestaurant.css';
import errorImage from '../../assets/img/error.png';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';

function GererMonRestaurant() {

  const [alert, setAlert] = useState("");
  const [UserInformations, setUserInformations] = useState([]);
  const [RestaurantInformations, setRestaurantInformations] = useState([]);
  const [imageRestaurant, setImageRestaurant] = useState("");
  const [hasRestaurantCompleted, setHasRestaurantCompleted] = useState("");

  console.log(UserInformations);
  //console.log(UserInformations[0].id);
  console.log(RestaurantInformations);
  //console.log(RestaurantInformations.data[0].name);

  const getUserInfo = async() => {
    await(Axios.post("http://localhost:3001/get-user-informations", {
      mail: sessionStorage.getItem("email"),
      password: sessionStorage.getItem("password"),
    })
    .then((response) => {
      if (response.data.message) {
        setAlert(response.data.message);
      } else {
        setUserInformations(response.data);
        //console.log("Le serveur me renvoie isRestCompleted = " + response.data[0].isRestaurantCompleted);
        if(response.data[0].isRestaurantCompleted === 0){ // la réponse est 0 donc formulaire d'ajout
          setHasRestaurantCompleted(false);
          //console.log("hasRestoCompleted = " + hasRestaurantCompleted);
        } else { // la réponse est 1, le restaurant a été renseigné
          setHasRestaurantCompleted(true);
          //console.log("hasRestoCompleted = " + hasRestaurantCompleted);
        } 
      }
    }));
  }; 

  const getInfosRestaurant = async() => {
    await(Axios.get('http://localhost:3001/get-restaurant-infos', 
    { params: 
      { id: localStorage.getItem('id') } 
    }).then((response) => {   
      setRestaurantInformations(response.data);
      //console.log(RestaurantInformations.data[0].image_resto);   
      //console.log(response.data[0].id);
      setImageRestaurant('http://localhost:3001/upload/' + RestaurantInformations.data.image_resto);
    }));
  };  


  useEffect(() => {
    //console.log("hello");
    getUserInfo(); 
    getInfosRestaurant();  
    //console.log("hasRestCompleted = " + hasRestaurantCompleted);        
  }, []);    
    
   

    return(
        <div>
            <div className='mainContainerGererMonResto'>
                { 
                hasRestaurantCompleted ? <div className='XXX'>

                  Vous avez renseigné un restaurant :
                  <img src={imageRestaurant} alt="imgRestaurant"/>

                </div>  
                : <div className='restoNonRenseigne'> 

                    <img className="errorImg" src={errorImage} alt="errorImg" />
                    <p className='whiteCardText'> Aïe ! Vous n'avez pas encore renseigné votre restaurant dans notre base de données. <br></br>
                    <Link to='/ajouter-mon-restaurant'>Lancez-vous</Link> dans l'aventure Foodelivery ! </p>

                  </div>
                }      
            </div>
        </div>                    
    );

};

export default GererMonRestaurant;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the time of render, the value of the image is yet undefined, since its async. Try setting the state in useEffect.

```
 const getInfosRestaurant = async () => {
   const response = await Axios.get('http://localhost:3001/get-restaurant-infos', 
    { params: 
      { id: localStorage.getItem('id') } 
    };
     return response;
  };
```

Then in useEffect,

```
 useEffect(() => {
 
        getUserInfo(); 
        getInfosRestaurant().then(res=>{
           setRestaurantInformations(response.data);

           setImageRestaurant('http://localhost:3001/upload/' + 
                        RestaurantInformations.data.image_resto);
        });        
      }, []);
```